# How do I search for characters excluding alphabet and numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to search all my columns and rows and only get the cells that have a character not in the English alphabet or numbers from 0 to 9 using excel without any plugins.

I just want to be able to see where the cells where there is no alphanumeric character.

all cells should be processed and check is there is a character that is not Aa-Zz or 0-9

I'm using excel office 2013. Is this possible?
I don't know how to do this, and I was wondering if this was possible with excel.

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried? What do you want to do with the cells you find?  Must the *entire* cell be Not-English or Not-Numeric?

Comment: Could you give some examples and expected results?